# problem with latest Eclipse plugin for Black Berry - unable to find scroll view

Tags: plugins, blackberry

I have a Black berry application and the targeted device 8520 has 4.5 os and i have eclipse helios (latest one), when i try to run the app it will compile and install the app

but when i try run the app it is displaying "Error Strating: ..Ui.ScrollView not available"

kindy help me to resolve this issue

Thanks,
Nag

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView is only available in 6.0 and above devices. Check what JDK you're compiling against, and you'll probably see that it isn't 4.5.